# performSelector:@selector error

Tags: xcode, delegates, controller, selector

Im trying to make this xcode project work but when it reach this method:

```
- (void)xmlReaderDidFinishedParsingDocument{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:@selector(setControllersBanner)];
}
```

show the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RadioStationAppDelegate setControllersBanner]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e66940'
```

someone could please tell me why it throw this error message, thanks in advance !

Comment: RadioStationAppDelegate does not implement setControllersBanner method. Check your app delegate implementation

Comment: I had it implement in the main controller